# Field value not persisted after import

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-import-export

**Model.py**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customerID =  models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    osm_bol = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    .....
    .....
    def __str__(self):
        return self.customerID
```

**Resouces.py**

```
class NewOrders(resources.ModelResource):
    osm_bol = Field(attribute='osm_bol', column_name='Client Track ID')
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('osm_bol')
```

**Exel Sheet Column**
[This is the Column that i want to import in my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qia8J.png)

**Problem**
the problem is i have the column name "Client Track ID" but in my model the name of attribute is "osm_bol" for the same field. when i import the file it shows nothing in "osm_bol" field. i mean its shows empty field. how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything is defined correctly except for your `fields` declaration.  Try to add a comma to turn it into a valid tuple:

```py
fields = ('osm_bol',)
```

Some other things to try:

- Use the Admin interface if you are not doing so already - this may give an message about any other errors - make sure you are importing the correct format (e.g. 'xlsx')
- Step through with a debugger (this is the fastest way to spot the error).  If you cannot do this, then add print statements
- Double-check your imports: is `Field` imported from `import_export`?
- Use the [example application](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app) - and work from there to understand why your implementation is not working.

Comment: Tried, But same result :(

Comment: thank you so much , I tried almost everything that you mentioned but its just not working . So now i am using PANDAS which very flexible and easy.

Comment: no problem - glad you found a workaround